# Contador de productos en Navbar

Tags: html, python-3.x, django

tengo un sitio en Django 3.1, donde hice un carro de compras, de momento todo funciona bien, y en la pagina donde tengo el catalogo el contador funciona perfecto.

El problema es que quiero colocar el contador en el navbar, que se encuentra incrustado en una plantilla base llamada "plantilla.html", por lo tanto al ingresar a cualquier pagina, el contador no funciona ya que nose hace un "Request" directo al metodo navbar ubicado en mi Views.py, por lo cual queria saber como pueda pasar esa información a mi navbar.html, y que el contador se vea en todas las paginas que utilizan plantilla.html como base.

Aqui van los codigos.

Views.py

```
def navbar(request):
usuario = request.user
carro = Carro.objects.filter(id_carro=usuario.id)
if carro:
    contador = Carro.objects.filter(id_carro=usuario.id).count()
    data = {'contador':contador,'carro':carro} 
return render(request, "navbar.html", data)
```

plantilla.html (no me deja pegar todo el codigo html)

```
          {{ contador }}
```

Saludos y muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta solución es la que yo utilizo para mostrar notificaciones en mi NAVBAR.

Talvez no sea una solucion perfecta pero es muy buena.

Consiste en crear un template.context_processors.
Primero te dejo un ejemplo como yo lo he implementado y al final te dejo una solución posible para tu caso

**Settings.py**

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                #..Debajo de los demas..
                "mysite.site_template.extra_context", # El context_processors modificado
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

.......

**site_template.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from notifications.models import Notification



def extra_context(request):

    
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        subject_events = Notification.objects.filter(Target=request.user, ).exclude(Actor=request.user)[:7]
        subject_new_events = Notification.objects.filter(Target=request.user, is_read=False).exclude(Actor=request.user)
        events_num = subject_new_events.count()

    else:
        subject_events = None
        subject_new_events = None
        events_num = None


    return {'base_url': settings.BASE_URL, 'base_site': settings.BASE_SITE,'events':subject_events, 'events_new':subject_new_events, 'events_num': events_num, }
```

......

**Template.py**

{{events_num}} Aqui pasamos un valor numerico .count de la cantidad de notifiaciones

{% if events_new %} Esto verifica si hay notificaciones nuevas por usuarios

{% for event in events %} Esto es para mostrar una lista de objetos event, desde un desplegable.

**Estas variables son globales se pueden usar en todo el sitio**
Tener en cuenta que cada vez que cargas cualquier vista se harán consultas en la bace de datos.

...

**En tu caso puedes hacer algo como esto.**

```
def extra_context(request):
    
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        contador = Carro.objects.filter(id_carro=request.user.id).count()
        carro = Carro.objects.filter(id_carro=request.user.id)


    else:
        contador = None
        carro = None

    return {'contador': contador, 'carro': carro }
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me funciono perfecto!

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar las sesiones de Django para mantener un valor en el request entonces así estará disponible para las distinas Views:

```
    # En la vista donde calculas el contador
    contador = Carro.objects.filter(id_carro=usuario.id).count()
    request.session['contador'] = contador

    # En cualquier otra vista donde quieres utiliza el contador
    contador = request.session.get('contador', 0)
    data = {'contador':contador}
```

También ten en cuenta que deberás mantener actualizado ese contador en la sesión por si llegas a modificar la cantidad del contador en cualquier otro lado que no sea en el catálogo.

Más info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Sessions
https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.2/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: Hola, si bien me funciona si cargo la navbar.html individualmente, no funciona cuando se carga el navbar incrustrada en plantilla.html, ya que no se hace una request directa al metodo navbar desde views.py, como se puede hacer para que en cualquier pagina que lleve el .plantilla.html(base.html) cargue el metodo del navbar?

Comment: Creo no estoy entendiendo bien del todo como estas renderizando los templates, imagino que el navbar es como una porción de html que se repite a lo largo de varias páginas no es cierto? y en que momento estas renderizando plantillas.html? en la función que pusiste solo veo que renderizas navbar.html